# Convergence of Related Series

Tags: real-analysis

Motivated by member @cmi's post:

" If $a_n > 0, \forall n \ge 1$, and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = +\infty$, study the convergence of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{1+n^2a_n}$ ". The outcome to this question is "convergence" by comparing the series with $p$-series for $p = 2$. In attempting to try another way to prove it divergent that I know won't succeed, I came up with the following series:

$a)$ $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{n+a_n}$. My quetion is does this series also diverge? given that $a_n > 0, \forall n \ge 1$, and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = +\infty$. Any one gives it a try? Is AM-GM inequality useful here? any well-known series could be involved?

Also, how about the divergence of $b)$ $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{\dfrac{1}{n} + a_n}$ ?

Comment: Did you mean "does this series also converge" ? $a_n=1/n $ gives convergence

Comment: Diverge is of interest. If you can prove it converge it is nice.

Comment: Maybe you forgot some constraint or I'm missing something, but $a_n=1/n $ gives convergence while $a_n=1/\log (n+1) $ gives divergence

Comment: For b, for the terms to converge to $0$, you would need $a_n \to 0$, but then $\frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n}+a_n} \ge a_n$ for large $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)

- with $a_n=1$, $\dfrac{a_n}{n+a_n}=\dfrac{1}{n+1}$ and the series diverges
- with $a_n=\frac 1n$, $\dfrac{a_n}{n+a_n}=\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}$ and the series converges

b) The series $\displaystyle \sum_{n} \dfrac{a_n}{\dfrac{1}{n} + a_n}$ always diverges. Indeed, if it were convergent, for $n$ larger than some $N$ we would have $ \displaystyle \frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n} + a_n} \leq \frac 12 \iff a_n \leq \frac 1n$, and then $\displaystyle \frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n} + a_n}\geq \frac{na_n}2 \geq \frac{a_n}2$.

But since $\sum_n a_n$ diverges, then $\displaystyle \sum_n\frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n} + a_n}$ would diverge too, a contradiction.